# Different ways of Creating Toast Notification in Windows store App

Tags: notifications, uwp

I am able to create the toast in two ways (XML and Notification toolkit). What is the difference in a toast that is created and which is efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are equivalent. The toolkit provides wrapper functions that generate the XML. This is easier and less error prone, but ultimately both send the same XML toast data.